# NSDate format causing trouble reformatting

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I have a `NSDate` value that looks like this `2013-03-20` which I think is `YYYY-MM-dd`. I would like to know how to `reformat` it so it looked like this `20-March-2013` but I just cannot figure it out.

This is what I have tried but its returning null.

```
NSDate *tempsDate = [tempDic objectForKey:@"date"];
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyy"];
            NSString *textDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:tempsDate]];
            NSLog(@"Date %@",textDate);
```

Comment: What is your current log date?

Comment: So tempsDate = 2013-03-20
and my NSLog = "Date (null)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, and please note that **i didn't test it**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter =  [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *displayString = [NSDate stringForDisplayFromDate:[tempDic objectForKey:@"date"]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: displayString];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
NSString *newFormattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: That worked perfect, I only had to take out the autorelease and it worked sweet. Oh and I changed the output yea to yyyy instead of yy